# How can I avoid getting chased down by an enemy UFO?

Tags: xcom-2

I've been expanding my influence in XCOM 2, but I'm still very early on in the game so my characters are not very powerful nor do I have high end gear. I've attempted the battle that occurs when you encounter the UFO, but it's absolutely brutal at this point in the game. I tried reloading a few times but no matter what I do this UFO seems to chase me down in a few days. What can I do to prevent this from happening?

A dark event claims to cause the UFO to not seek you out anymore, but I did that event earlier and I'm still encountering this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as my personal experience goes, I am not sure that you have many options.

### 1. Prevention

Of course the best solution to prevent being attacked by an UFO is to counter the dark event before it takes place. It is not always possible to do so, of course.

### 2. Evasive maneuvers

If you fail to prevent the dark event to happen, you have a chance to be attacked from the ufo sometimes soon. When an UFO is in pursuit trajectory, you will have a warning message that offers you the possibility to implement evasive maneuvers (basically, fly off your current position and hope to avoid the fight). This attempt is not always successfull, but for me it worked 2 times out of 3 so far.

---

Well I understand that this looks bleak and the ground defence mission is quite difficult. I also found it quite enjoyable, but I had a fairly extensive and experienced soldiers rooster, so that might be a difference. But do not be afraid, there are no unwinnable missions in the game, no matter how difficult they look! Here are some tips that I found useful during that mission

### Be FAST

The mission will get harder the longer you play it. So you should try to reach the first objective as soon as possible, and then try to have an all-out retreat to your base camp. The longer it takes, the more reinforcements will be dispatched

### Have a lot of soldiers ready

Central will dispatch to the mission all non-gravely wounded soldiers (not sure if all, but in my playthrough I managed to deploy 9 soldiers) your reserves every other turn. Of course the more soldiers you can deploy, the easier is to defend the Avenger.

### Upgrade your Avenger

In mid-game there is a room called Defence matrix that you can research. That room gives you some automated turrets to defend yourself with during the mission.

Comment: "there are no unwinnable missions in the game" Really?? I can't say for sure in this game yet, but in the old game if you fell behind on the strategic layer, the tactical missions could certainly become unwinnable!

Comment: @SimonW sure but they were not designed to be unwinnable, that's what I meant. There is always one way out.

Comment: By fast, they mean within the first few turns. I took 18 turns on this mission and ended up killing 35 enemies, with 8 wounds and 1 death. I feel I got off lightly.

Comment: I actually found the defense mission surprisingly easy. Mostly because the AI seemed to prioritize getting closer to the Avenger over effectively fighting my troops, which lead to it making some really stupid decisions. I had one Advent trooper do a double-move right through my formation into a position where half my team could flank him.

Comment: another way is if you have a ranger with the individual concealment you can take him around the edge of the map and get him to spot for you squad sight snipers, you can't miss the objective at all and it will go down to 2-3 shots depending on your weapons. Do this while overwatching everyone else in the exit zone and you should be able to win easily

Comment: There are always a Heavy MEC somewhere near the Disruptor Device. I've hacked it and done job by it. All of my troops stood on the ramp and nearby trees. The mission was flawless.

Answer (score 5):

it takes a few turns for the enemy reinforcements to start dropping, so if you're quick with the pre-existing squads on the map you can overwatch every single drop and have all or most of them down right after they land (just be sure not to run out of ammo on everyone at the same time)

to take those first squads out do not be afraid to use explosives to clear cover and add some damage on those first squads.

currently using the mission to farm experience for all my troops (half of which were still rookies, and everyone just has starting gear)